# Is there a way to use std::sort() and still maintain a 1 based indexing?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want my array to maintain a 1 based indexing even after the `sort()` is completed. My code below gives me a garbage value at the last index when `i = n` because the loop should have been
`for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` while printing the code after the sort is completed.
 Is there a way to use `std::sort()` and still maintain a 1 based indexing?

```cpp
int n;
cin >> n; // 6
int a[n+1];
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    cin >> a[i]; // INPUT ARRAY: 6 4 2 7 2 7
  
sort(a, a+n+1);
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    cout << a[i] << " "; //  OUTPUT AFTER SORTING: 2 4 6 7 7 6421920
```

Comment: ...but why are you using one-based indices?

Comment: Working on a coding problem that requires a lot of indexing work. I didn't want to keep using ```i - 1``` each time. Otherwise I always use 0 based indexing.

Comment: The program is ill-formed. The size of an array must be known at compile time in C++.

Comment: This is still a bad reason to use 1 based indexing, writing `i - 1` is not a big deal. As you've already witnessed, things are designed around 0 based indexing.

Comment: Yeah it's ill-formed. Tried to make a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Actually, I'm solving an old programming question on a programming contest website (codeforces). They have given constraints on the size of the array.

Comment: Yes, true everything is designed around 0-based indexing. Will keep an eye on that next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes, only sort starting from index 1.

```
std::sort(a+1,a+n+1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way. Just omit the dummy element when you call `sort`:

```cpp
sort(a+1, a+n+1);
```